# yii Session gets cleaned on every request

Tags: php, session, yii

Example of my code:

```
class SiteController extends Controller {

    /**
     * This is the default 'index' action that is invoked
     * when an action is not explicitly requested by users.
     */
    public function actionIndex() {

        $_SESSION['test'] = 'testdata';
        var_dump($_SESSION); exit;
    }
```

Example on the second request:

```
class SiteController extends Controller {

    /**
     * This is the default 'index' action that is invoked
     * when an action is not explicitly requested by users.
     */
    public function actionIndex() {

        var_dump($_SESSION);exit;
    }
```

I have a project in yii. Project not mine - I'm just trying to fix errors.

My problem is: 
first var_dump() shows that $_SESSION variable HAS the "test" index with "testdata". On the second request though I get an empty array of $_SESSION variable. Meaning, that every request session gets cleaned up. I've checked - the session ID stays the same. I've also checked this projects config - i can't find any references to extending SESSION component and changing it's behaviors. Also, when logging in yii DOES save states into SESSION, but the login fails because of SESSION being cleaned after redirect. That is to say COOKIE BASED authentication works which just proves the root of the problem.

Would very much appreciate help.

**UPDATE**

---

I've narrowed it down. This is the code for FRONT YII FRONT CONTROLLER(index.php):

```
<?php
    @session_start(); // this line is at cwebuser.php at init() method and it is called at every request. should work properly.
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    $_SESSION['test'] = 'asdasd';
    var_dump($_SESSION);exit;
```

It still prints empty $_SESSION on the second REQUEST. So the problem is probably not with the framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can set session details in your `/protected/config/main.php` (this is the default unless you have changed it in index.html)

```
    'session' => array(
        'autostart' => true,
        'timeout' => 1440, // time in seconds
    ),
```

Read about Session on [`CHttpSession`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I accessed my website via server ip : 123.123.123.123/site/index and this has conflicts with accessing and saving the session. Though I don't know the details. If someone has knowledge on this stuff I will gladly accept his(her) answer as the right one.

Answer (score -1):

There is a file called controller.php under protected/components/controller.php which will be called before any action get called .. u can check that file and see... is there done any logout function  calledthere...

```
//It clears all the sesstion data... or any php way
Yii::app()->user->logout();
```

Yes if u are in moule then u can also check ModuleName.php under module directopry ... if there is any session clearing script...

which clears the session... And yes this is not the right way of using session in Yii yes it is PHP but YII .... u can use folowing sytax dfor sessions..

```
//to set a session variable mnamed test
Yii::app()->user->setState('test',$test);
//to get a session variable named tets
Yii::app()->user->getState('test');
```